# Java xml serialization with null fields

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I have a class with an Integer field and I need to serialize to xml. If the element is null I need to see empty string in the xml. Example:

```
  <myObj field=""/>
```

Whatever I tried, I could not achieve this. I tried something like this :

```
public class MyObj {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    @JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)
    Integer field;
}
```

How can I achieve that I would be grateful for your help

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. `field=""` is not a valid `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the @f1sh comment,
empty string ("") is not a valid Integer value.

With Jackson,
you can create create a custom serializer
(and will need a custom deserializer).

This [Baeldung page](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) may help.